# Could a null column be part of a primary key?

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2012

I'm developing a SQL Server 2012 database and I have a question about a One-to-Zero-Or-One relationship.

I have two tables, `Codes` and `HelperCodes`. A code could have zero or one helper code. This is the sql script to create these two tables and their relationships:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Code]
(
    [Id] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    [Level] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [CommissioningFlag] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [SentToRanger] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    [LastChange] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [UserName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Source] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Reason] NVARCHAR(200) NULL, 
    [HelperCodeId] NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Code] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [Id] ASC
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Code_LevelConfiguration]
       FOREIGN KEY ([Level])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[LevelConfiguration] ([Level]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Code_HelperCode]
       FOREIGN KEY ([HelperCodeId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[HelperCode] ([HelperCodeId])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HelperCode]
(
    [HelperCodeId] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    [Level] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [CommissioningFlag] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [LastChange] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_HelperCode] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [HelperCodeId] ASC
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_HelperCode_LevelConfiguration]
       FOREIGN KEY ([Level])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[LevelConfiguration] ([Level])
)
```

Is that correct?

A Code and a HelperCode are both different entities. A HelperCode can be an used (none Code references it), or used (only one Code references it).

Maybe Code.HelperCodeId must be part of Code table primary key. But I'm not sure if a null column could be part of a primary. Doing this, I want to prevent that two or more Codes reference the same HelperCode.

Comment: Why would you want `HelperCodeId` to be part of the PK? Is it, by any chance, because you want to prevent two or more Codes to reference the same HelperCode?

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent that two or more codes reference the same HelperCode. Another option is to set `HelperCodeId` column as Unique.

Comment: @ypercube Could you please add the complete sql sentence as answer? I don't work very often with sql and I don't know how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Conceptually, the DBMS engineers couldn't have permitted NULLs in primary keys without going against the entire relational data model.  And the relational model is part of what makes relational databases so useful.  You may or may not be interested in this aspect, but it's important to point out for future visitors.

Comment: @WalterMitty I never understood why having a null value in a PK would destroy the value that an RDBMS brings. I have heard it many times. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Oversimplifying the relational model usually does more harm than good.  Having said that, I'll throw in my two cents.  First off, I would say "damage" rather than "destroy".  Second, Ed Codd is quite explicit about what harm is done by systems that are "almost relational".  I don't always believe everything he wrote, but he has more crdibility than I do, by far.

Comment: In part, it depends on what NULL means.  NULL means different things to different people.  I believe the real meaning is "no data here".  Whether that means "not applicable", "not available", or as in this case "no relationship" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: If NULL really means "no data here", then what is the answer when we ask "are these two keys different"?  Well, if all the values are filled in, it's easy.  If all the values are the same, then the keys are the same.  If one or more of the values is different, then the keys are different.  If one of the keys contains a missing value, the answer could be "maybe".  This is where things start to fall apart.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, no, all the primary columns have to be `NOT NULL`.

But without altering the design of the tables, you could add a filtered index on the `Code (HelperCodeId)` column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX 
    FUX_Code_HelperCodeId
ON dbo.Code 
    (HelperCodeId) 
WHERE 
    HelperCodeId IS NOT NULL ;
```

The filter (`WHERE HelperCodeId IS NOT NULL`) is needed because of the way SQL-Server treats nulls in unique constraints and unique indexes. Without the filter, SQL-Server would not allow more than one row with `NULL` in `HelperCodeId`.

---

An alternative design would be remove the `HelperCodeId` from `Code` and add a third table that will store the `Code` - `HelperCode` relationships. The relationship between the two entities seem to be Zero-or-One--to--Zero-or-One (both a Code can have no HelperCode and a HelperCode might be used by no Code):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Code]
(
    [Id] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    [Level] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [CommissioningFlag] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [SentToRanger] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    [LastChange] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [UserName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Source] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Reason] NVARCHAR(200) NULL, 
    -- 
    -- removed:   [HelperCodeId] NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
    -- 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Code] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [Id] ASC
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Code_LevelConfiguration]
       FOREIGN KEY ([Level])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[LevelConfiguration] ([Level]),
) ;
```

`HelperCode` remains unchanged:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HelperCode]
(
    [HelperCodeId] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    [Level] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [CommissioningFlag] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [LastChange] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_HelperCode] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [HelperCodeId] ASC
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_HelperCode_LevelConfiguration]
       FOREIGN KEY ([Level])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[LevelConfiguration] ([Level])
) ;
```

The additional table will have two `UNIQUE` contraints (or one primary and one unique) to ensure that every Code is related to (maximum) one HelperCode and each HelperCode is related to (maximum) one Code. Both columns would be `NOT NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Code_HelperCode]
(
    [CodeId] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    [HelperCodeId] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [UQ_Code_HelperCode_CodeId]
       UNIQUE (CodeId),
    CONSTRAINT [UQ_Code_HelperCode_HelperCodeId]
       UNIQUE (HelperCodeId),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_HelperCode_Code]
       FOREIGN KEY ([CodeId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Code] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Code_HelperCode]
       FOREIGN KEY ([HelperCodeId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[HelperCode] ([HelperCodeId])
) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, you could alter the design if you want. I could learn a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your design. I haven't added a new table because I thought these tables are used only in many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a unique constraint instead. Supposedly the ANSI standard declared nulls as a primary key to be invalid, but I have never seen the standard and don't wish to purchase it to verify this.

Not having null keys seems to be one of those things that developers have a very hard belief on one way or the other. My preference is to use them because I find it helpful for lookup tables containing tooltips and related data for comboboxes that are not been populated.

I was taught that Null value indicates that a variable has never been set and empty value indicates that the value has been set in the past. Of course this is up to the developer to define for the application, but I find it nonsensical to allow empty primary keys but not null primary keys.

Comment: If you try `SELECT '' = '';`, you get `true` as the result. If you try `SELECT NULL = NULL;` you get `NULL` as the answer (which would likely be interpreted as `false`). If you want to know whether a cell is null, you need to use `cell IS NULL` to get `true`. If you try `cell = NULL`, it won't work. Having a special case for the primary key would be very difficult to deal with.